# GCC Cloud Function internal server error 500

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cloud, scheduler

I have a firestore database that I want to backup regulalry using google cloud's scheduler alongside google cloud function. I am following this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#gcp-console.

I am using Node.js 16 with 2 GB of RAM with the code below:

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME'

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
    process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    '(default)'
  );

  return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      collectionIds: [],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
    });
};
```

When I test the function it just returns an Internal Server Error 500. Any ideas?

Also, here is a picture of the errors im getting from the logs:

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: edited original post